# SSH RSA public key in PKCS1 format issue

Tags: c#, git, ssh, ssh-keys

I've created private & public key using GIT bash. I got id_rsa as private & id_rsa.pub as public key from ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 command. The problem is when i am using c# code for abenity api, it gives error that "Not an RSA key". My private key is as follows-

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIJKAIBAAKCAgEAvg5KIzv59e9l9OKhRorkGQloGH60jMRCdiyxVPZtHDGfbr+N
I5RIpvuv5rhE2ADm+LsaF7HkInEslTVwjjg2piznkc99yAm7y2PsBJQDvhbvdXtM
eJV1JzFEKzBcbuPvVZ/wmcdSENmUXgz
ZltPdTX9WPYPQqmMb6iS+NRqowvYV7zzJTsuL6rDmRGhReH0R27yDihEFx8hC6mQ
x+r..............................Ir2NLnc=
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

And my public key as follows -

```
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAACAQC................G+KssB6SPx+WbGpmW
```

I think my public key should be in PEM Format:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBCgKCAQEA05ulw0FHaD3yCw8zPhav2lVdasl5waVSyl
MKvJ+YJuE9hifO3R8XslKWYW2cOTg0QPQIDAQAB
-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
```

However, i do not know how to convert it into above format. Need help!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Export the key:

```
ssh-keygen -e -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub -m pem >ssh-pub.pem
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply dear, I got my public key as below format:


-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBCgKCAQEA05ulw0FHaD3yCw8zPhav2lVdasl5waVSyl
MKvJ+YJuE9hifO3R8XslKWYW2cOTg0QPQIDAQAB
-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----

from ssh-keygen -e -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub -m pem but now I'm getting error in abenity api response as 


{"method":"sso_member","status":"fail","error":"Encryption Signature Failed"}